# Does $a_n = \frac {1}{1*2^2}+\frac {1}{2*3^2}+...+\frac{1}{n*(n+1)^2}$ converge?

Tags: analysis

Prove that the following sequence is convergent if:

$a_n = \frac {1}{1*2^2}+\frac {1}{2*3^2}+...+\frac{1}{n*(n+1)^2}$
My solution 
$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{1*2^2}+\frac{1}{2*3^2}+...+\frac{1}{n*(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)*(n+2)^2}$. Which can also be written as $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{(n+1)*(n+2)^2}$

$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1+\frac{1}{(n+1)*(n+2)^2*a_n}$

Now, I do not know if the limit of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ is equal to 1 or $ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \in [0,1) $

Comment: What have you tried? What are your thought on the problem? what criterions do you know for convergence of series?

Comment: It is a series and the notation $a_n = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac {1}{n(n+1)^2}$ is meaningless.

Comment: I have tried D'Alembert criteria, either I misscalculated or it is not the way to solve it. Also I had a small atempt to use weierstrass theorem

Comment: Maybe you mean  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{n(n+1)^2}$? or  $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n  \frac {1}{k(k+1)^2}$?

Comment: The sequence converges by the comparison test with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3}$. I doubt this is the kind of proof you’re looking for, though.

Comment: @SavoiuMihai Maybe it could take a look to some resource on tah subject, for example [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SeriesIntro.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence we are considering is

$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k(k+1)^2}$$

and its limit is denoted as [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)), that is

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k(k+1)^2}$$

Now you should be aware about the following foundamental result

$$\forall p>1, \quad\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{n^p} <\infty$$

and of the comparison test which states that

$$0\le b_k\le c_k, \quad \sum c_k<\infty \implies \sum b_k<\infty$$

in our case we have that

$$b_k=\frac1{k(k+1)^2}=\frac1{k^3+2k^2+k}\le c_k= \frac1{k^3}$$

therefore the series converges.